# XCode 8 wrong views resoltion

Tags: ios, xcode

I am currently developing an iOS 10 app using XCode 8. But for some reasons on all devices the view bounds are 1024x768 pixels. I googled around very much, found some informations about launch screen images. I added them in the correct resolutions, etc. Created app icons in the right resolutions but it does not work.

Am I missing some settings that it runs on an iPad Pro with full resolution? The project is configured as universal.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Using Launch images isn't the way to go anymore. You should explore using a Launch Screen storyboard. Also, what resolution are you expecting? 1024x1366 is the 12.9" iPad Pro. and all other iPads will report 1024x768 for the bounds. You would supply 2x and 3x images to account for the higher resolution screens.

Comment: Interesting. The problem I get from this is when creating an EAGLcontext and rendering opengles stuff. that has a too small res and it just looks very pixelated...

Comment: You should update your question to reflect the actual problem. I suspect the issue isn't that the encompassing view is 1024x768 but that it's something to do with how you are setting up the EAGLcontext and pinning its edges. If you have sample code of how you are setting up the context that will also probably help someone give you a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's iOS 10 new features. Now all views has 1000x1000 frames after viewDidLoad. You can check this in UIViewController's viewDidLoad method. (all but self.view, it still has values from xib/storyboard file).

If your constraints is correct, you can get values in viewDidLayoutSubviews. I mean this is there you need to check view size.